# Any ideas for how to use solar to offset electricity in an apartment?

Tags: solar-panels, solar

I have 2 solar panels and a deck that is east and south facing, so it gets plenty of sun. I've been trying to see if there's a way to use those to help offset electricity in an apartment. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Do you own the apartment or rent?

Comment: additional useful information needed, what rating are the panels? 100 watt each? 150 watt each? do you have a charge controller?

Comment: Unless these are very large (250W or bigger) panels, its just not likely to be worth the trouble. Assuming an electricity cost of 15 cents per Kwh, a pair of 250W panels catching 6 hours of strong sunlight, might make 3 Kwh of power per day - 45 cents worth of energy, which would knock a whole 13 bucks off your monthly bill.

Comment: @Harper renting the apartment, so I can't install anything on the roof.

Comment: @fred_dot_u 100 watts each, but will be adding more.

Comment: @Norm I'm mainly looking for ideas. I'm wondering if it can be done in a rented apartment and what would be involved, not if it's worth the trouble. I will be getting more solar panels and would love to have them be used when I'm in the apartment.

Comment: You would have to do it in such a way as to not tie into the apartments electrical system (the management is 99% certain to not allow you to do that). So you are pretty much left with setting it up to run just a few select items that draw under 200 watts. A desktop computer, or maybe a TV...

Comment: As a tenant, I can't think of any ways that aren't ridiculous.  Best I can come up with is sell the panels on Craigslist and use the proceeds to buy "shares" in a commercial solar farm in a better location, say, the Mojave Desert.  Yhe cheapest way to transport electricity from A to B is arbitrage it to money, and transport the money.  It also works that solar is peaker, so your commercial farm is collecting top price for peak power, while your home is paying the normal all-day tariff, so you're actually doing pretty good arbitrage.

Comment: I have a 12v system I use for lighting, music, security, and a few oddball things I got at a truck stop.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a regulator (appx $88 at a local supplier) and storage battery(ies) ($77 for a 35AH, same supplier), to feed low voltage lighting ($11 per 750 mah array) at night. However, since you are paying around $0.11/KWH at the wall, it will take a long time to break even on the expense of a) battery b) regulator, c) wiring, and d) low voltage lighting. The same money spent on increased insulation would likely provide a much quicker return on your investment.

Comment: Off grid systems don't provide a return on investment - they never break even because of the expensive batteries that don't last (or the VERY expensive batteries that do last). They are best used when the cost of hooking to the grid is extreme ($20k just to connect) or for the independence aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Solar hot water works on the principle of creating/storing solar energy slowly so it can be used later.

We use it to pre-heat water for our hot water heater.

Comment: The original poster wants a solution using electrical panels, not heat collectors. Not a bad idea, though.

Comment: @K7AAY I think most electric companies will tell you hot water use is about 25% - 30% of total electric use. Space heating / cooling represents about 40% - 60% of electric use. However, is much more difficult to incorporate into a heating system. Installing batteries, etc. to power lights, etc. doesn’t save much, but if you can save half your hot water electric cost...then you’re saving.